# Programmatically display keyboard in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, webkit

If an element in a UIWebView has the style property -webkit-user-modify:read-write, then pressing on the element causes the keyboard to appear.  Is it possible to bring up the keyboard programatically?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe apply that style to the body?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like in iOS6 now you can do this with "**keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction**":

keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction
A Boolean value indicating whether web content can programmatically display the keyboard.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction
Discussion
When this property is set to YES, the user must explicitly tap the elements in the web view to display the keyboard (or other relevant input view) for that element. When set to NO, a focus event on an element causes the input view to be displayed and associated with that element automatically.

The default value for this property is YES.

Availability
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
Declared In
UIWebView.h

reference:

Answer (score 3):

From [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW18):

> Because the keyboard is displayed automatically when a view becomes the first responder, you often do not need to do anything to display it. However, you can programmatically display the keyboard for an editable text view by calling that view’s becomeFirstResponder method. Calling this method makes the target view the first responder and begins the editing process just as if the user had tapped on the view.

I doubt that calling `[webView becomeFirstResponder]` will bring up the keyboard as long as no HTML element with the required style has the focus. So your real problem might be to set the focus in your HTML document to an element programmatically. I would try to do this via Javascript. Something like this might work:

```
NSString *jscode = @"document.getElementById('whatever').focus();";
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jscode];
```

Comment: No luck with that.  I should also say that I have put a canBecomeFirstResponder method in my UIWebView that simply returns YES, and put a breakpoint in the method.  When I touch an element with the style property, the keyboard comes up, without the canBecomeFirstResponder being called.  Interestingly, the method is called when I touch the Done button on the input auxiliary view.

Comment: Can you post them HTML-Code your UIWebView is showing? Eventually it would help in finding a Javascript-function which does what you want.

Comment: The HTML has this script in the header

Comment: <script type="text/javaScript">
        var touchedElement ;
        
        window.addEventListener('touchend',function(event)
        {    touchedElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.changedTouches[0].screenX, event.changedTouches[0].screenY) ;
      touchedElement.style.webkitUserModify = "read-write" ;
             touchedElement.focus() ;
        window.location = "app://navigate" ;
        },false) ;
</script>

then return YES in the delegate shouldStartLoadWithRequest method, and execute [self.view becomeFirstResponder] in the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method.

Comment: Then return YES in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method, and call [self.view becomeFirstResponder] in the webViewDidFinishLoad method.

If I can get that to work, then I'll use more control over when the keyboard is displayed in response to a touch.

Comment: I think that this doesn't work because it is some other object, not the web view that becomes the first responder when the element is touched, as evidenced by the canBecomeFirstResponder method not being called on the web view until the Done button is touched.  I'm thinking that there may be a webkit javaScript function that will cause the keyboard to come up, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I found too many posts from people trying so solve exactly the same problem but all of them failed. This seems to be a really tough one! Good luck ;-)